How to aggregate nested manytomany relationships in django orm
Given the pseudo definitions:
class User:
    name: string
    
class Account:
    owner: foreignkey(User, related_name="accounts")

class Transactions:
    type: Enum(1,2,3)
    account: foreignkey(Account, related_name="transactions"
    value: Int

How do I write this query using django ORM?
SELECT user.id, type, AVG(value) as type_average
FROM user
JOIN account ON account.owner = user.id
JOIN transactions ON transactions.account = account.id
GROUP BY user.id, type


You .annotate(…) [Django-doc]:
from django.db.models import Avg, F

User.objects.values(
    user_id=F('pk'), type=F('accounts__transactions__type')
).annotate(type_average=Avg('accounts__transactions__value')).order_by(
    'user_id', 'type'
)

You can create a view in your database for this query and map a Django model to it afterwards, or try using the ORM like this:
from django.db.models import Avg, F

result = User.objects.annotate(type=F('account__transactions__type'),
type_average=Avg('account__transactions__value')).values('id', 'type', 'type_average')

